# Correctly displaying significant figures

Tags: libreoffice

I have a table. Columns B and C contain data. I want to set the values in column D to B/C. I used this formula: `= <B2>/<C2>`. This works, but it doesn't correctly display significant figures. Here is an example:

```
B       C       D
5.60    1.1     5.09 (should be rounded to 5.1)
```

When dividing, the result should have no more significant figures than the number with the least significant figures. I did find [a forum post](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=25658) that had a formula to round a number to only display a certain number of significant figures:

> =ROUND(A1,A2-1-INT(LOG10(ABS(A1))))

It only displays a set number (A2) of significant figures, however. I need the number of significant in the result to depend on the number of significant figures in the inputs. How can I do this in LibreOffice?